# sql query for deleting similar rows

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am having a trouble with following cases:

1. duplicate except id(primary key)
2. all fields are the same except id(primary key) and finish_time

[image]

My question is how to remove one row from the 1st result, but also remove the row that has null value in finish_time field. The final expected result is the one below: 
[image]

Thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

like this

```
    delete from t
    where id IN
    (select distinct on (task_id, date) t.id
    from t
    order by task_id, date, finish_time nulls last) as sub
```

Answer (score 2):

You can keep one row using `distinct on`:

```
select distinct on (task_id, date) t.*
from t
order by task_id, date, finish_time nulls last;
```

Comment: Thank you! It seems to work ok. 
Do you know how I can delete the rest of rows which are contained in the result from the query above??